# Saving Google Maps Center and Zoom in iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, casting, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have yet to be able to find an answer to my issue. I have a map with multiple markers for numerous reasons. I am able to repopulate those markers with no issue when a user moves to another scene/view/view controller. What I am having an issue with is the current center point and zoom level. The primary issue is not getting the coordinates or zoom level but storing those values in a variable type that can be checked to see if the value is empty or not. Here's how it should work:

1. User opens app and populates map with markers. Those markers are used to automatically refit the map based on the bounds of the markers.
2. User segue's to another scene/view/view controller. At this point, the center point (latitude/longitude) and zoom level need to be saved to one or more variables.
3. User comes back to the map scene/view/view controller. The app needs to check if there was a previous center point and zoom level saved and if there was, use that center point and zoom level to draw the map. If not, use the defaults.

Any help is appreciated. I have tried using Floats, Doubles, and Coordinate types however, when trying to check for nil or empty, it fails because all of these can be 0 since (0,0) is a valid point.

Comment: Much of your question is unrelated to your issue. Narrow down the question to just the relevant part. Update your question with some relevant code. Show what you need to accomplish and what you have tried.

Comment: I completely disagree with your statement. Read my question(s) again please. All I am trying to do is set variables in the AppDelegate to the current center and zoom level of the map when the user changes from my map view controller to another controller. The problem I am having is the variable type's it is telling me to use (Double, Float, Coordinates) cannot be checked for NIL because 0,0 is a valid latitude and longitude.

Comment: Half of your question talks about all the things that work. No need for any of that info. You need about two sentences talking about the need to store a coordinate including the ability to set a "null" value. And then add some code showing what you have and how it isn't quite sufficient and why.

Comment: Really? You're going to beat me up over too much information? Good lord! If I don't give enough information, people give me shit. If I provide too much information, people give me shit. Get over yourself "rmaddy" and don't bother responding unless you can help someone.